# An algorithm to positioning windows GWT

Tags: java, windows, algorithm, gwt, positioning

Using GWT I want to implement an algorithm which set windows (rectangles) in other, bigger window (also a rectangle). 
Each window has a start point (x, y) and procentage value of width and height which determines a position and size in large Window.
After add/remove any small window, from large, remaining small windows should fit sizes (depends on basic values) to completly fill large window.
Split small window into pieces is not allowed. At any moment (after add or remove window) remaining small windows should fully cover large window.
Is there any function or algorithm I can use to simplyfy my work or I must write in my own?